# Swift. Is it possible to determining property time at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, design-patterns, 3d

I have the next problem:

I have a class which can contain some data of different type but the type of the data is not known at compile time.

It looks like this

```
class Data {
    var dataType: PodDataType = PodDataType.None

    var componentsCount: UInt32 = 0

    var stride: UInt32 = 0

    var data // the data type of this field is unknown until dataType property is initialized
}
```

And I have another class which have multiple Data instances it looks like this:

```
class Mesh {

    var verticesCount: UInt32 = UInt32.max

    var facesCount: UInt32 = UInt32.max

    var UVWChannelsCount: UInt32 = UInt32.max

    var vertexIndexes: Data?

    var stripLength: UInt32 = UInt32.max

    var stripsCount: UInt32 = UInt32.max

    var vertex: Data?

    var normals: Data?

    var tangents: Data?

    var binormals: Data?

// and so on ...
}
```

Every time I create an new object of Data it should contain different data type in its 'data' field. What is the best way to solve such issues?

My thoughts:
1) AbstractFactory pattern: I can create base class Data and many subclasses like DataInt, DataFloat etc. but this means that I need to create subclass for every supporting type (int32, int8 and 15 types more).

2) Generics: I can define Data like this class Data, but after that my Mesh class become dependent from the Data class because there is no way to define generic class without type parameter.

3) UnsafePointer I can store data using this pointer but I not sure will the data persist if the NSData object from which I read the info is deallocated. Also what about the performance type casting from UnsafePointer to actual type.

Any other practices of this situation are highly appreciated.

P.S. I am developing parser for Pod file which stores 3D graphics data.
POD File Format Specification can be found [here](http://community.imgtec.com/files/pod-file-format-specification/) as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using `Any`?:

```
class Data {
    var dataType: PodDataType = PodDataType.None
    var componentsCount: UInt32 = 0
    var stride: UInt32 = 0
    var data: Any?
}
```

But I think this is the good use case for [`enum` with associated values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148):

```
enum PodData {
    case Ints([Int])
    case Floats([Float])
    // ...
    case None
}
```

Comment: How can `Any` determine the type at runtime?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad By `dataType` property.

Comment: Then the property determines the type. With a `switch` cascade?

Comment: Sooner or later, we have to `switch` and cast to retrieve the payload.

Comment: Sooner or later, a runtime environment could do that without `switch`.

Comment: rintaro is right we determine the type by the initialization of dataType property which value (integer with id of specific type) goes before the data block in the file. @amin-negm-awad I also see the only way to cast the data to a specific type using switch. If you have other opinion share it please.

Comment: I do not think that you have another choice in Swift. This is because of its static typing nature. You could consider writing a part in Objective-C. Another solution could be to write an access protocol for the data and type the property to that protocol instead of a type. However, I wrote a comment, not an answer to underline the basic problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to this in Swift is to make a property for each type and just use one for each instance. Simple, safe, and very little redundancy.

The only other viable alternative is to find a data format that can describe all the data types you want, e.g. `String`. But you will have to invest time to engineer reliable conversions for reading and writing. There is obviously a price in efficiency you have to pay.

Comment: The usual approach in Swift, not the usual approach.

Comment: Right you are. I changed the wording.

Comment: BTW: Having i. e. 17 properties instead of 1 is not little redundant, but 1,600 % overhead.

Comment: No, that would be 17 *data types*, very unlikely. Plus, you are not storing any data in the empty slots, so the overhead would still be minimal.

Comment: "(int32, int8 and 15 types more)"

Comment: Yes, but his example shows that OP does not need them. It's an academic question.

Comment: Yes, does it? However, I did not answer, but posted a comment.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you could make use of first and second approach combined.

Make use of Abstract Factory pattern with concrete class for primitive class with Generics. It will make your life a bit easier.

```
class BaseData {

}

class PrimitiveData<T> : BaseData {

}

class UserDefinedData : BaseData {

}
```